# Is it possible to make a shopping cart persistent in Ubercart

Tags: cookies, drupal, shopping-cart, ubercart

I would like users to be able to have persistent shopping carts. In other words, unless they check out the shopping cart explicitly the shopping cart with the same items should be available the next time they visit the site. Obviously this would be through the use of a cookie...

Is this possible in Drupal?

Comment: if they are logged in, that is how it works by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is right in Ubercart. You can set the cart time to whatever you please.

There is **duration** and **units** for anonymous and separate settings for logged in.

Visit this on your site: admin/store/settings/cart/edit/basic